# Set Custom "Paragraph Type Icon" For Paragraph Type With Module During Install

Tags: 8, forms, paragraphs

Drupal 8.x

I have a paragraph that is installed via a custom module, this is done with `.yml` files in the `MYMODULE/config/install/` directory. I would like to have a custom icon added to the "Paragraph type icon" field for the Paragraph type during install.

Example config export after manually uploading an image after the paragraph type is installed:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  content:
    - 'file:file:328b219f-01e9-4dfd-8fdd-c304fcf6e368'
id: paragraph_name
label: 'Paragraph Name'
icon_uuid: 328b219f-01e9-4dfd-8fdd-c304fcf6e368
description: ''
behavior_plugins: {  }
```

The icon value is set/exported as a `uuid`, I am wondering how I can set this field value during install using an icon that resides in my module folder?

I have functioning config files and .module file.